# jQuery tablesorter 2.31.1 resizable table with long text problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I have the problem that tablesorter snaps all columns when i try to rezise.
The column width is not applying with `resizable_widths` correctly, only after I resize a column.
I set the width = 120pxon all cells, but cells with text longer than 120px cause the problem with the snapping.

Here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/L614kyeh/

If you try to resize the column `Columxyz` the `Name` Column gets smaller.
How can I prevent this?
I tried to set the width with `!important` of all cells but the width is not applying.

If I set `resizable: true` it only snaps when I visit the site the first time. After that it remembers the column width. But it should work from the beginning.

I hope somebody can help.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying:
I build a new example with the help from: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-resizable.html

now it does'nt snap anymore but if I set `resizable: false` it applies not the width properly. But thats ok for now.

https://jsfiddle.net/gsoq1wmj/